# What is the probability of a function being Riemann Integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functions, soft-question, riemann-integration

Suppose we are given a set $F =\{f|\ f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}\}$, i.e. an arbitrary set (not sure about its countablility) of real-valued functions. What is the probability, that a function $f_k$, chosen at random from the set is Riemann Integrable?

Note: I came up with this problem entirely on my own. So, if there are any "loose-statements", please correct it. I don't have enough knowledge to even approach this. There might be some duplicates out there, which I am not sure of. Is this even a valid question?

Thank you.

Comment: Depends on $F$ and the distribution you put on $F$. In most "natural" ways to do this that I can think of, the probability will be either 0 or 1, depending on whether $F$ consists only of "nice" functions or not.

Comment: does it require the knowledge of measure?

Comment: That also depends on how you do it, but doing anything interesting with this question will probably need some measure theory, yes.

Comment: The probability of a function to be Riemann Integrable is probably close to zero. Of course,  if you are thinking at the functions encountered by students the probability is higher. And even more if you consider the functions in textbooks. Sorry of this answer, as fishy as the question itself.

Comment: @JJacquelin Can the probability be thought to be highly "localised"? Kind of like the Dirac Delta?

Comment: Sort of; the Lebesgue criterion tells you that Riemann integrable functions can't be too far from being continuous in some sense, and there is a vast availability of nowhere continuous functions out there.

Comment: @Ian I think it kind of boils down to the problem of finding the probability of a function being continuous.

Comment: Your set $F$ is not "a" set yet to be specified, but a very definite set. None of the functions in this set is Riemann integrable since Riemann integrals refer to bounded domains. Etcetera.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter I am going to modify the domain to $[a,b]$. Now?

Comment: If you actually mean that $F$ is the set of *all* functions from $[a,b]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ then there's pretty much no reasonably "uniform-ish" distribution on that which will assign positive probability to the Riemann integrable functions.

Comment: @Subhasis Biswas . Let $f(x)$ be a Riemann integrable function. Let $h(x)$ any non Riemann integrable function ( they are an infinity of them). The function $h(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ is non Riemann integrable. Thus for one Riemann integrable function, you got an infinity of non-Riemann integrable functions.